# Riddle of my buddy

Tags: riddle

> There came a bird rainbow, flew out of your window.
>
> My mind is filled with complete emptiness.
>
> Whenever you give me a gesture, I wake up to meet you.
>
> Then I wander around in Paradise like a vagabond.
>
> We loved each other when you were so young,
>
> but when you come to me too close, I shy away from you.

What am I?

---

Hint 1

> The bird is featherless.

Hint 2

> I'm a classic puzzler in arcades.

Hint 3

> A specific, common object.

Hint 4

> I'm unsustainable in the long run.

Comment: Another riddle :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Answer

Are you

> A bubble

There came a bird rainbow, flew out of your window.

> Colorful when light shines through

My mind is filled with complete emptiness.

> Filled with air

Whenever you give me a gesture, I wake up to meet you.

> ave your hands to for a bubble (between fingers)

Then I wander around in Paradise like a vagabond.

> float in the air

We loved each other when you were so young,

> kids like making bubbles

but when you come to me too close, I shy away from you.

> blown away when getting close to it

Hint 1

> The bird is featherless.

Hint 2

> I'm a classic puzzler in arcades.
>  Bubble Bobble

Hint 3

> A specific, common object.
>  Bubbles are very common

Hint 4

> I'm unsustainable in the long run.
>  Bubbles have to pop, they can't live forever

OLD answer:

Are you

> Pac-man

There came a bird rainbow, flew out of your window.

> Colorful ghosts are let loose from a box

My mind is filled with complete emptiness.

> Arcade cabinets are mostly empty inside? (not sure)

Whenever you give me a gesture, I wake up to meet you.

> Put coins in the game to start playing

Then I wander around in Paradise like a vagabond.

> Going from level to level in the game

We loved each other when you were so young,

> The game was made in 1980, so a lot of people started playing it when they were kids

but when you come to me too close, I shy away from you.

> The orange ghost chased you, but ran away when you got close

Comment: Cool. Your new answer is correct. Could you add more explanations about how the answer fits the hints too?

Comment: And the window a bird flies into?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer anyway.

Comment: Not really sure about the windows and the bird, sorry...
English is not my first language, so maybe I'm missing something :)

Comment: It's alright. This has been neglected for like more than a week so I just kinda wanted to finish it up. Many thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> A shadow

There came a bird rainbow, flew out of your window.

> 

My mind is filled with complete emptiness.

> Shadows don't have minds

Whenever you give me a gesture, I wake up to meet you.

> When we move the shadow moves as well

Then I wander around in Paradise like a vagabond.

> A reference to the movie "Shadows in Paradise" maybe

We loved each other when you were so young,

> Kids like to play with shadows (like making shadow figures with hands)

but when you come to me too close, I shy away from you.

> If you walk towards it, it will keep moving in the direction you are moving

Comment: Nice guess. Though this one is way different from what I'm looking for. ROT13(Nabgure pyhr vf gung vg'f pnyyrq n oveq orpnhfr bs gur snpg gung vg syvrf nebhaq.)

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> sleep/dreaming? you are dreaming about bird rainbows and our mind is empty when we sleep, whenever you move too much, you wake up, then you fall asleep again and wander in paradise. You loved sleeping when you were a baby, it was pretty much all you did, and if you try to sleep too fast you won't be able to, since you will only be thinking and not relaxing

Comment: Good one. xD But sadly, although I like your idea a lot, there is another answer I'm waiting for.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a rainbow bird that has nothing inside of it? XD

Jk this is a joke

Probably gonna get a lot of down arrows but oh well :)

Comment: I got the idea from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Featherless_bird-riddle) but it didn't seem to work out well.